# How to read RINEX files with Python?

Tags: python, gps, pyephem

I'm looking for a way to read GNSS RINEX files with Python. 
Most importantly I would just need to get orbital information read from a RINEX navigation file elements so that I could use PyEphem for follow-up processing. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

[PyRinex](https://github.com/scienceopen/pyrinex) currently supports reading RINEX 2 navigation files. You did not specify if you require RINEX 3 support. I have not used PyRinex myself. A quick look at the code seems to show that it only supports decoding GPS navigation files (e.g. *.YYn).

Answer (score 0):

PyEphem, at least, does not have any knowledge of the RINEX format — it can only understand the TLE format for satellite ephemeris files.